# Saving memory on image synchronization on Android

Tags: android, image, synchronization, base64

I got a piece of code like that and it is actually working fine. The only concern that I have is that it convert image to base64, and it seems to eat lots of memory.

I would love to know if there is any better ways to do it.

```
// SYNCING IMAGES
    private boolean syncImages() {
        boolean update = false;

        for (Asset asset : assets) {
            // Get all images for the asset (list) -> get string name of image (string)
            List<Image> remoteAssetImages = RESTfulService.getInstance().getAssetImages(asset.getId());
            ArrayList<String> remoteAssetURIs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Image img : remoteAssetImages)
                remoteAssetURIs.add(img.getImageId() + ".jpg");

            for (String remoteURI : remoteAssetURIs) {
                if (!asset.getImages().contains(remoteURI)) {
                    long imageId = Long.parseLong(remoteURI.replace(".jpg", ""));
                    // Perform synchronous get request
                    try {
                        Bitmap img = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load("http://www.google.com/image" + imageId + "/jpg")
                                .get();
                        saveRemoteImage(getApplicationContext(), img, imageId, asset);
                        asset.setConcatenatedImageURI();
                        AssetDatabaseHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateAsset(asset);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    update = true;
                }
            }

            Iterator<String> uriIterator = asset.getImages().iterator();
            while(uriIterator.hasNext()){
                String uri = uriIterator.next();
                if (!remoteAssetURIs.contains(uri)) {
                    String base64Image = getBase64EncodedImage(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                    ImageData postImage = new ImageData(6, asset.getId(), base64Image);
                    RESTfulService.getInstance().postImage(postImage);
                    renameImageFile(getApplicationContext(), asset, uri, postImage.getImageId()+".jpg");
                    AssetDatabaseHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateAsset(asset);
                }
            }
        }

        return update;
    }

    public static void renameImageFile(Context context, Asset asset, String currentName, String newName){
        File originalFile = context.getFileStreamPath(currentName);
        File newFile = new File(originalFile.getParent(), newName);
        if (newFile.exists())
            context.deleteFile(newName);
        originalFile.renameTo(newFile);
        asset.getImages().remove(currentName);
        asset.addImage(newName);
        asset.setConcatenatedImageURI();
    }

    public static String getBase64EncodedImage(Context context, String imagePath){
        Bitmap bmp = getImageBitmap(context, imagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageDataBytes = stream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageDataBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The reason it eats a lot of memory is because it loads the entire string into memory and can cause OOM exceptions with large images.

When you upload an image its better to upload an image in chunks of data to save the memory and prevent OOM exceptions

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please? How can I upload images in chunks of data? Thanks.